how to work non respiinding amplify cli package?
i installed amplify cli
when i look up if it's installed
kang@Kangui-noteubug ~ % which amplify /Users/kang/.nvm/versions/node/v20.17.0/bin/amplify
it shows this but
when i try to use it
kang@Kangui-noteubug ~ % amplify -v kang@Kangui-noteubug ~ % /Users/kang/.nvm/versions/node/v20.17.0/bin/amplify -v
nothing happens
using node 18
tried reinstall nvm, node,
delete npm cache,
recheck environment variables,
edit package permissions
